# Getting SVG filters to work on CSS background-image

Tags: html, css, svg-filters

I have created an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/L6j4pqss/) which is supposed to rotate the color channels of a CSS background-image using an SVG filter. The CSS used for the filter is:

```
.filt1 {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\' xmlns:xlink=\'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\'><filter id=\'filt1\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#filt1");
}
```

However, it is having no effect on the image, either in Chrome or Safari.

What am I doing wrong? Are you able to fork and edit my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/L6j4pqss/) so it works?

The CSS for the image div is as follows:

```
div {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/zDPDlNd.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: The SVG fiter ID looks very odd

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think you can reference a filter that's inside a URI encoded SVG. Why aren't you defining the filter in an SVG fragment inside your HTML?

Comment: @MichaelMullany: Because I'm doing it another way. And I'm doing it that way because plenty of posts have it as a suitable approach. But I've also tried referencing a separate svg file and that doesn't work either.

Comment: It works fine as a -webkit-filter when the filter is moved into an SVG fragment. Either your escaping is wrong or you can't reference a fragment like this.